# Showing multiple views from different applications in Android

Tags: android, module

I am working on a Android project where we have designed the system with the idea that anyone should be able to write a new 'module' for the overall system(that module being a separate package), and have it be able to interact with it as long as the namespace is kept the same.

To visualize this, imagine a Manager application that keeps track of data and provides a ContentProvider for other applications in the system. These applications can then use this ContentProvider to read and write data to the database. These other applications are one of three types, a sensor type that records data, an analysis type that uses recorded data and summarizes it in some way and a view type that provides a specific visualization of the data.

One of the things we want to do is take a series of view modules and display their visualizations in the Manager, on the same page, and as I understand it defining an Activity or Fragment in these views would require you to open a new Activity with an Intent, moving away from the Manager and only having one source of visualization instead of multiple, which is not the intended behaviour as what we want is to show multiple views from multiple modules on the same page on the Manager.

Now we did find a way to do this(Create the view programmatically in one application, and load it remotely from the other class), but it feels extremely hacky and I would really like to know if there is a better way to go about doing this.

I should say that this is an educational project(not homework though - this question is just using a valuable resource), and the time is limited so we do not as such have time to change the architecture but I do think we are somewhat perverting the intended use of Android application design.

CommonsWare questions how we actually load the custom view, this is how:

```
public View getView(String packageName, String className, String viewName)
{
    String apkName = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).sourceDir;
    PathClassLoader myClassLoader = new PathClassLoader(apkName, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    Class<?> handler = Class.forName(className, true, myClassLoader);
    Constructor[] m = handler.getConstructors();
    View returnView = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < m.length;i++)
    {
        if(m[i].getName().contains(viewName))
        {
            Log.i("Blah", m[i].getName());
            returnView = (View)m[i].newInstance(new Object[]{context});

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Create the view programmatically in one application, and load it remotely from the other class" -- are you referring to `RemoteViews`? If so, that's the engine behind app widgets and custom notifications, and it's the best-supported approach for this sort of UI-over-IPC.

Comment: @CommonsWare - The edit should explain how we do it, I hadn't even heard of RemoteViews, that might be worth looking into.

Comment: Yeah, from a maintainability and security standpoint, that's not exactly an ideal approach. Also note that AFAIK your loaded classes would have no access to their original apps' resources, though you might be able to work around that by using `createPackageContext()` for the parameter you are passing into the foreign view's constructor.